# Roots of equation with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Finally I got  two equations:

\begin{align}
z^3&=-\sqrt{3}+i \tag1 \label1 \\
z^3&=-\sqrt{3}-i \tag2 \label2.
\end{align}

So there are six roots.
It is easy to get two of them:
$z_1=(-\sqrt{3}+i)^{1/3}$ for \eqref{1} and $z_4=(-\sqrt{3}-i)^{1/3}$ for \eqref{2}.

However, I am not sure how to apply the rotatation to get the rest of the roots?
According to answer the roots are:
\begin{alignat}{2}
z_2&=\frac {1} {2}i(-\sqrt{3}+i))^{4/3} \quad&
z_3&=(-1)^{2/3}(-\sqrt{3}+i)^{1/3} \\
z_5&=-(\sqrt{3}+i)^{1/3} &
z_6&=-\frac {1} {2}i(-\sqrt{3}-i)^{4/3}.
\end{alignat}
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Are you familiar with DeMoivre's theorem?

Comment: @Hyperion Yes, thank you. I tried it and got the roots which have cos and sin functions with 5pi/6 angle. However, it is far from the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply DeMoivre's theorem to solve for $z^3 = -\sqrt{3} + i$. Rewriting in polar form, we find that $-\sqrt{3} + i = 2(\cos(5\pi/6) + i\sin(5\pi/6))$.

Applying DeMoivre's theorem to get our first cubic root, we find that
$$z_1 = 2^{1/3}(\cos(5\pi/18) + i\sin(5\pi/18))$$.

To get our second $z$ value, we need to rotate our answer around the pole by $2\pi/3$, then apply this rotation once more to get our third $z$. Rotations correspond to "adding angles" in polar form, and thus, our other two roots are

$$z_2 = 2^{1/3}(\cos(17\pi/18) + i\sin(17\pi/18))$$
$$z_3 = 2^{1/3}(\cos(29\pi/18 ) + i\sin(29\pi/18))$$

You can try to apply this principle yourself to get the last $3$ roots from your other equation.

Comment: Thank you, however, I am not sure how to convert your answers to the mentioned at the beginig. I got the roots from https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E3%3D-%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%2Bi

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/imaginary-and-complex-numbers/polar-form-of-complex-numbers/v/polar-form-complex-number